# Writing a program to find Length C of a triangle

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write a program to find side C of a right triangle, given the length of sides A and B. Here is what I have so far:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Math
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // Scanner scan = new scanner(system.in);
        int a, b, c;
        int length c; c = sqrt(a^(2)+b^(2))

        System.out.println("Length of side a?");
        a = scan.nextdouble();

        System.out.println("Length of side b?");
        b = scan.nextdouble();

        c = math.sqrt(a^(2)+b^(2));

        System.out.print("The length of side C is");
        System.out.println(c+ "units.");

        scan.close();

    }
}
```

Eclipse tells me I have an argument error but I don't know what to suspect. Any advice on fixing this? I know it's simple, and I feel like the solution is right in front of me.

Comment: it doesnt really matter that its eclipse. java programs look the same in any other IDE

Comment: remove the line int length c; c = sqrt(a^(2)+b^(2)) then run your program again

Comment: *Eclipse tells me I have an argument error but I don't know what to suspect.* - I would suspect the line that Eclipse marks as containing an error. Your code has too many issues to be covered in a single answer. A small list: `math` should be `Math`, `^` is for XOR, `int length c;` is not valid syntax. `scan.nextdouble()` should be `scan.nextDouble()` (and you've commented out the declaration of `scan`), and others.

Answer (score 1):

change this `int length c; c = sqrt(a^(2)+b^(2))` to `int length;`

Comment: You mean `int length;`. `c` is already declared in the previous line. Also `a` and `b` are uninitialized at this point. The entire line should just be removed.

Comment: oops.. sorry. You are right. Didn't see C was declared above. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

The ^ symbol is the same as XOR. It does not mean "to the power of". You will need to use

```
Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2);
```

or

```
a*a + b*b
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a lot of errors... this is the working version:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Math
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // this had errors
        double a, b, c; // doubles are better for division, 
                        // unless you want imprecise results

        System.out.println("Length of side a?");
        a = scan.nextDouble(); // note the case in the method name, this was wrong

        System.out.println("Length of side b?");
        b = scan.nextDouble(); // same here

        c = java.lang.Math.sqrt(java.lang.Math.pow(a,2) + java.lang.Math.pow(b,2));

        System.out.print("The length of side C is ");
        System.out.println(c + "units.");

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Since you named your class Math, you have to use the full java.lang.Math prefix for sqrt and pow.

Comment: @JasonC Sure no problem. Except, since the class is names Math i think it clashes with the static Math.pow and sqrt.

Comment: I rolled back my edit because I didn't notice that. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

remove  `int length c;` 
first **length** is not used and **c** is already declared.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you managed to make so many mistakes..

this is a working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lame {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a, b, c;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Length of side a?");
        a = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Length of side b?");
        b = scan.nextDouble();

        c = Math.sqrt((a*a + b*b));

        System.out.print("The length of side C is");
        System.out.println(c+ "units.");
    }

}
```

Some hints. Pay attention to your Capitalization. Java is case sensitive. 
scanner and Scanner are not the same thing in java!  (Classes are capitalized while functions are not)

Java does not automatically convert types
you cannot set a= scan.nextDouble(): because it will return a double not an int. 
(if you want to cast a double to int you must do it yourself)

there is no such thing as a power sign ^ in Java. You need to either use a pow() function or just do a variable times itself like a*a.

Change your class name from Math.

Try google things and do a lot of exercises from the book just coping the code. After a while you will start understanding things.